# How to get total ETA time and the first ETA time in that block using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file that I need to get the total ETA time per block and the first ETA time instance of that block. Here is an example of my data.

```
*****START OF YOUTUBE*****

VIDEO

[download]   0.0% of 5.30MiB at 188.75KiB/s ETA 00:29
[download]   0.1% of 5.30MiB at 474.99KiB/s ETA 00:11
[download]   0.1% of 5.30MiB at 984.97KiB/s ETA 00:05
[download]   0.3% of 5.30MiB at  1.85MiB/s ETA 00:02
[download]   0.6% of 5.30MiB at 896.97KiB/s ETA 00:06
[download]   1.2% of 5.30MiB at 888.54KiB/s ETA 00:06
[download]   2.3% of 5.30MiB at 1006.45KiB/s ETA 00:05
[download]   4.7% of 5.30MiB at 916.41KiB/s ETA 00:05
[download]   9.4% of 5.30MiB at 863.70KiB/s ETA 00:05
[download]  18.9% of 5.30MiB at 847.73KiB/s ETA 00:05
[download]  34.2% of 5.30MiB at 843.72KiB/s ETA 00:04
[download]  49.7% of 5.30MiB at 840.54KiB/s ETA 00:03
[download]  65.0% of 5.30MiB at 839.77KiB/s ETA 00:02
[download]  80.5% of 5.30MiB at 839.71KiB/s ETA 00:01
[download]  95.9% of 5.30MiB at 839.39KiB/s ETA 00:00
[download] 100.0% of 5.30MiB at 842.74KiB/s ETA 00:00
[download] 100% of 5.30MiB in 00:06
AUDIO

[download]   0.0% of 2.99MiB at 112.61KiB/s ETA 00:27
[download]   0.1% of 2.99MiB at 311.43KiB/s ETA 00:09
[download]   0.2% of 2.99MiB at 682.19KiB/s ETA 00:04
[download]   0.5% of 2.99MiB at  1.32MiB/s ETA 00:02
[download]   1.0% of 2.99MiB at 943.80KiB/s ETA 00:03
[download]   2.1% of 2.99MiB at  1.17MiB/s ETA 00:02
[download]   4.1% of 2.99MiB at  1.31MiB/s ETA 00:02
[download]   8.3% of 2.99MiB at  1.59MiB/s ETA 00:01
[download]  16.7% of 2.99MiB at  1.37MiB/s ETA 00:01
[download]  33.4% of 2.99MiB at  1.03MiB/s ETA 00:01
[download]  60.8% of 2.99MiB at 942.47KiB/s ETA 00:01
[download]  88.1% of 2.99MiB at 908.52KiB/s ETA 00:00
[download] 100.0% of 2.99MiB at 897.53KiB/s ETA 00:00
[download] 100% of 2.99MiB in 00:03

MKV


*****END OF YOUTUBE*****

*****START OF YOUTUBE*****

VIDEO

[download]   0.0% of 41.89MiB at 251.26KiB/s ETA 02:55
[download]   0.0% of 41.89MiB at 612.01KiB/s ETA 01:10
[download]   0.0% of 41.89MiB at  1.23MiB/s ETA 00:34
[download]   0.0% of 41.89MiB at  2.33MiB/s ETA 00:18
[download]   0.1% of 41.89MiB at 783.21KiB/s ETA 00:54
[download]   0.1% of 41.89MiB at 959.46KiB/s ETA 00:44
[download]   0.3% of 41.89MiB at  1.16MiB/s ETA 00:36
[download]   0.6% of 41.89MiB at  1.45MiB/s ETA 00:28
[download]   1.2% of 41.89MiB at  1.15MiB/s ETA 00:35
[download]   2.4% of 41.89MiB at 986.82KiB/s ETA 00:42
[download]   4.4% of 41.89MiB at 912.91KiB/s ETA 00:44
[download]   6.3% of 41.89MiB at 877.92KiB/s ETA 00:45
[download]   8.2% of 41.89MiB at 870.89KiB/s ETA 00:45
[download]  10.2% of 41.89MiB at 865.95KiB/s ETA 00:44
[download]  12.1% of 41.89MiB at 862.33KiB/s ETA 00:43
[download]  14.1% of 41.89MiB at 859.01KiB/s ETA 00:42
[download]  16.1% of 41.89MiB at 857.18KiB/s ETA 00:42
[download]  18.0% of 41.89MiB at 855.34KiB/s ETA 00:41
[download]  20.0% of 41.89MiB at 850.76KiB/s ETA 00:40
[download]  21.9% of 41.89MiB at 850.71KiB/s ETA 00:39
[download]  23.9% of 41.89MiB at 850.61KiB/s ETA 00:38
[download]  25.9% of 41.89MiB at 850.12KiB/s ETA 00:37
[download]  27.8% of 41.89MiB at 849.74KiB/s ETA 00:36
[download]  29.8% of 41.89MiB at 849.08KiB/s ETA 00:35
[download]  31.7% of 41.89MiB at 848.78KiB/s ETA 00:34
[download]  33.7% of 41.89MiB at 846.31KiB/s ETA 00:33
[download]  35.6% of 41.89MiB at 844.42KiB/s ETA 00:32
[download]  37.5% of 41.89MiB at 844.68KiB/s ETA 00:31
[download]  39.5% of 41.89MiB at 844.87KiB/s ETA 00:30
[download]  41.5% of 41.89MiB at 844.76KiB/s ETA 00:29
[download]  43.4% of 41.89MiB at 844.93KiB/s ETA 00:28
[download]  45.4% of 41.89MiB at 844.77KiB/s ETA 00:27
[download]  47.4% of 41.89MiB at 843.37KiB/s ETA 00:26
[download]  49.2% of 41.89MiB at 843.65KiB/s ETA 00:25
[download]  51.2% of 41.89MiB at 843.66KiB/s ETA 00:24
[download]  53.2% of 41.89MiB at 843.50KiB/s ETA 00:23
[download]  55.2% of 41.89MiB at 843.46KiB/s ETA 00:22
[download]  57.1% of 41.89MiB at 843.19KiB/s ETA 00:21
[download]  59.1% of 41.89MiB at 843.22KiB/s ETA 00:20
[download]  61.0% of 41.89MiB at 842.88KiB/s ETA 00:19
[download]  63.0% of 41.89MiB at 843.00KiB/s ETA 00:18
[download]  65.0% of 41.89MiB at 842.80KiB/s ETA 00:17
[download]  66.9% of 41.89MiB at 842.91KiB/s ETA 00:16
[download]  68.9% of 41.89MiB at 842.09KiB/s ETA 00:15
[download]  70.8% of 41.89MiB at 842.40KiB/s ETA 00:14
[download]  72.8% of 41.89MiB at 840.95KiB/s ETA 00:13
[download]  74.6% of 41.89MiB at 840.38KiB/s ETA 00:12
[download]  76.5% of 41.89MiB at 840.77KiB/s ETA 00:11
[download]  78.5% of 41.89MiB at 840.21KiB/s ETA 00:10
[download]  80.4% of 41.89MiB at 840.45KiB/s ETA 00:09
[download]  82.4% of 41.89MiB at 840.65KiB/s ETA 00:08
[download]  84.4% of 41.89MiB at 840.80KiB/s ETA 00:07
[download]  86.4% of 41.89MiB at 840.35KiB/s ETA 00:06
[download]  88.3% of 41.89MiB at 840.73KiB/s ETA 00:05
[download]  90.3% of 41.89MiB at 840.32KiB/s ETA 00:04
[download]  92.2% of 41.89MiB at 840.69KiB/s ETA 00:03
[download]  94.2% of 41.89MiB at 840.31KiB/s ETA 00:02
[download]  96.1% of 41.89MiB at 840.64KiB/s ETA 00:01
[download]  98.1% of 41.89MiB at 840.26KiB/s ETA 00:00
[download] 100.0% of 41.89MiB at 840.32KiB/s ETA 00:00
[download] 100% of 41.89MiB in 00:51

AUDIO

[download]   0.0% of 10.35MiB at 114.98KiB/s ETA 01:32
[download]   0.0% of 10.35MiB at 317.99KiB/s ETA 00:33
[download]   0.1% of 10.35MiB at 694.85KiB/s ETA 00:15
[download]   0.1% of 10.35MiB at  1.37MiB/s ETA 00:07
[download]   0.3% of 10.35MiB at 846.04KiB/s ETA 00:12
[download]   0.6% of 10.35MiB at  1.14MiB/s ETA 00:09
[download]   1.2% of 10.35MiB at  1.29MiB/s ETA 00:07
[download]   2.4% of 10.35MiB at  1.71MiB/s ETA 00:05
[download]   4.8% of 10.35MiB at  2.00MiB/s ETA 00:04
[download]   9.7% of 10.35MiB at  1.17MiB/s ETA 00:07
[download]  17.7% of 10.35MiB at 985.70KiB/s ETA 00:08
[download]  25.3% of 10.35MiB at 940.66KiB/s ETA 00:08
[download]  33.3% of 10.35MiB at 916.90KiB/s ETA 00:07
[download]  41.4% of 10.35MiB at 900.34KiB/s ETA 00:06
[download]  49.3% of 10.35MiB at 885.27KiB/s ETA 00:06
[download]  56.9% of 10.35MiB at 880.58KiB/s ETA 00:05
[download]  65.0% of 10.35MiB at 876.17KiB/s ETA 00:04
[download]  73.0% of 10.35MiB at 868.96KiB/s ETA 00:03
[download]  80.7% of 10.35MiB at 867.56KiB/s ETA 00:02
[download]  88.7% of 10.35MiB at 865.95KiB/s ETA 00:01
[download]  96.7% of 10.35MiB at 862.35KiB/s ETA 00:00
[download] 100.0% of 10.35MiB at 862.21KiB/s ETA 00:00
[download] 100% of 10.35MiB in 00:12

MKV

*****END OF YOUTUBE*****
```

The start point of per block is video to audio then another one is audio to mkv. The sample output of the first block should be:

```
First Block Video to Audio:
ETA TIME Instance = 00:29
Block ETA Time total = 01:35

Second Block Audio to Mkv:
ETA TIME Instance = 00:27
Block ETA Time total = 00:56
```

Until the end of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic solution:

```
from collections import deque
import re
import datetime

def print_block(first, last, first_eta, total_eta):
    print("First Block {} to {}:".format(first.capitalize(), last.capitalize()))
    print("ETA TIME Instance = {}".format(str(first_eta)))
    print("Block ETA Time total = {}".format(str(total_eta)))
    print()

def convert_to_timedelta(time_delta):
    blocks = time_delta.split(":")
    if len(blocks) == 2:
        return datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(blocks[0]), seconds=int(blocks[1]))
    else:
        return datetime.timedelta(hours=int(blocks[0]), minutes=int(blocks[1]), seconds=int(blocks[2]))


def process_chunk(chunk):
    queue = deque()
    first_eta = None
    total_eta = datetime.timedelta(hours=0,minutes=0, seconds=0)
    for line in chunk:
        # If line is a source change, add to queue.
        if line.isupper():
            queue.append(line)
            # If queue is full, pair sources and remove the first one.
            # Inner chunk can now be printed.
            if len(queue) == 2:
                first = queue.popleft() 
                last = queue[0]
                print_block(first, last, first_eta, total_eta)
                # Reset etas. 
                first_eta = None
                total_eta = datetime.timedelta(hours=0,minutes=0, seconds=0)
        else:
            # Find ETA **:** value. 
            m = re.search(r'ETA\s(.*)', line)
            if m is not None:
                time_delta = convert_to_timedelta(m.group(1))
                if first_eta == None:
                    first_eta = time_delta
                total_eta += time_delta

# Read file and split up into YOUTUBE blocks.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    chunk = []
    with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            # Process each youtube block seperately.
            if line.startswith("*****END OF YOUTUBE*****"):
                process_chunk(chunk)
                chunk = []
            else:
                line = line.rstrip()
                if line != '' and not line.startswith('*****START OF YOUTUBE*****'):
                    chunk.append(line.rstrip())
```

Which produces the following results (as per your example):

```
First Block Video to Audio:
ETA TIME Instance = 0:00:29
Block ETA Time total = 0:01:29

First Block Audio to Mkv:
ETA TIME Instance = 0:00:27
Block ETA Time total = 0:00:53

First Block Video to Audio:
ETA TIME Instance = 0:02:55
Block ETA Time total = 0:28:22

First Block Audio to Mkv:
ETA TIME Instance = 0:01:32
Block ETA Time total = 0:04:01
```

Note, total_eta is calculated by summing only values prefixed with ETA (and doesn't include the total timeline, which you did in your calculation). If you want to change that behavior simply change the regex.

Not the most memory efficent version (it's `O(n^2)`), but I figured readability was more important than speed. It could be modified to run in `O(n)` by processing chunks line by line (as opposed to once the entire chunk has been read).

Comment: It works! I'll just change the regex. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: is it possible also to get the hours and minutes of ETA first instance? Because some of my data for the first instance have minutes and hours.

Comment: Updated it (again you may have to change your regex if you want the last value for each chunk (`r'(\d*:*\d*:\d*)'` works). I've modified it so that it creates `timedelta` objects for each string match, and sums them directly. The `convert_to_timedelta` method is required because the string will be different for seconds/minutes (00:00), vs hours (00:00:00).